# The initial value is very different from what I set in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I create a neural network with the initial tensors like this

```
tensor_dict = {
    'model_conv1_weights': tf.get_variable('model_conv1_weights',
        shape=[4, 4, 1, 64],
        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10.0, stddev=2.0))
    'model_conv1_biases': tf.get_variable('model_conv1_biases',
        shape=[64],
        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=2.0, stddev=1.0))
    'model_conv2_weights': tf.get_variable('model_conv2_weights',
        shape=[4, 4, 64, 32],
        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=10.0, stddev=2.0))
    'model_conv2_biases': tf.get_variable('model_conv2_biases',
        shape=[32],
        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=2.0, stddev=1.0))
}
```

But when I start to train the model, the initial values of those tensors are very different from what I configured.

[image: snapshot of tensorboard]

Did anyone here meet this issue before?

Comment: What is your learning rate?

Comment: 0.1， Actually I tested many different learning rates in the model, but the it does not affect the initial value.

Comment: It looks like you must not have called session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

Comment: I already called sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
Now I found the key reason is because the initial value is a very big negative value, then all the output of that layer will be removed by the relu filter (all zero), then the whole layer will not be updated by the learning process. 
The initial value still the root cause for this issue.

Comment: I output some logs, It looks the data is OK at beginning, but after a flow iterations, All the values just jump to roughly -xxE12, and all the output of that layer becomes 0.

Comment: It sounds like training is diverging rapidly.  This could be in part due to the learning rate being set too high, but I would also consider changing your initializations.  Is there some particular reason you chose such high initial weights and biases?  In my experience, I generally get best results with small, slightly positive initial weights when using ReLUs.